# Finding an exact match in a string with difference sizes and with similar matches

Tags: python, parsing

I have to parse through a file (which I know how to do), however, I need to search for specific patterns in a string and this is where I'm getting a bit confused.

Let's say we have the following strings:

```
GEO1D1JXUQ2LSO

GOE22D2OKDLALKCDSI

EO212D0FM2KDLA

LAFD21D1FM2KDF3BLA
```

What are known about the strings are the prefix (GEO, GOE, EO,LAFD) and that there is 1, 2 or 3 numbers after the Prefix then the letter D, As shown in the example.

I have the prefixes beforehand, but that's it. How can I search through every string and identify which group it belongs to?

Note: there is some information in the string (like the number after the D) that I need as well but I'm only focusing on the how to identify which group it's part of so I can then grab more information of that group.

I am stuck because there are some prefixes that can exist within prefixes, like EO in GEO.

Comment: Have you tried anything in terms of code?

Comment: `EO` and `GEO` are not ambiguous if they are prefixes - just use `startswith()`.

Comment: Not yet, I have code for previous parsing like using re.compile with search and match, but for here I wanted to know how to go ahead with the problem

Comment: @Blorgbeard what about for prefixes AOI and AOIO?

Comment: For that case, can you just define the order of your checks such that `AOIO` is checked before `AOI`?

Comment: That's a good point, I'll have to find the very similar ones and do that. If you post an answer like that, I'll vote is as the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a regex to extract "all letters between the start and the first number", with something like `^([A-Z]*)[0-9]`

Comment: I like that solution better, then I can do a direct compare. Also, It could help with extracting other things like "first number to last number before letter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to check for a prefix is just `string.startswith()`.

If you have prefixes that are prefixes of other prefixes (e.g. `AOIO` and `AOI`), then you just need to be careful to define the order of your checks such that longer prefixes are checked first.

Alternatively, you can use a regex to extract the prefix, and the other information you need. An example:

```
^([A-Z]*)[0-9]+D([0-9]+)
```

This would give you two group captures, the first being the prefix and the second being the number after the `D`. See details here: https://regex101.com/r/GxSZSI/2

Example usage in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'GOE22D2OKDLALKCDSI'
>>> m = re.match('^([A-Z]*)[0-9]+D([0-9]+)', s)
>>> m.groups()
('GOE', '2')
```